# Convert JDeveloper Project to Maven

Tags: maven, jdeveloper

Im actually a release manager, and we are getting some JDeveloper Web Projects, now we have to convert this project to Maven or ANT but we dont have any idea of how to do this, im new on JDeveloper.

Any idea how to do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper has options to create Ant build for application or an application level POM (If you are aiming to use Maven you should upgrade to the latest JDeveloper to get a more complete Maven support).
Some examples:
Ant - 
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/oracle_developer_cloud_service_automating

Maven - 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/developer/BuildWithMaven/build_with_maven.html